# Importance of religion for a common man in medieval India

Tags: india, religion, early-medieval, religious-history

I have recently studied the rise of Islam and the origins of Bhakti movement in medieval India. All the sources that I have referred to talk of the spread of new religious ideas and people converting from one religion to another as something that happens on its own. However, in modern India, religion is a very sensitive subject for most people and converting from one religion to another or adopting a new religious philosophy is unthinkable and looked down upon by society. So my question is what did religion mean for an average Indian in the early medieval period. Why was it so easy to convert people? 
My prominent sources are: [A History of Sikhs](https://books.google.com/books/about/A_History_of_the_Sikhs.html?id=lVpGtAEACAAJ&hl=en) by Khuswant Singh 
NCERT textbook of history for class 8

Comment: Welcome to History SE. It would be useful for people trying to answer your question if you cited at least some of the sources you have referred to.